# (UNITY 3D): moving a camera along a rail/predefined path using mouse scroll input

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, mousewheel, cinemachine

this is my first post on this community. I searched around for some content to help me with my question, and I've found some stuff that could potentially help me but I just wanted to know if its possible to **move a camera along a fixed path using a mouse scroll input?**

What I'm thinking of is maybe using the track and dolly feature with cinemachine and perhaps moving to one waypoint with every scroll increment up/down, but as I am still a c# noob I dunno how I can do that.

Here is a reference for the kind of movement I want to do: https://www.sprite.com/zerolimits

Any help will be very much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Your hunch on using a track and dolly with Cinemachine is correct. What you can do is create a Virtual Camera with it's body set to Tracked Dolly and enable the `Auto Dolly` property. Then create a path using Cinemachine's Path script and add a reference to this path to the Virtual Camera.

Then create a separate empty GameObject which will be your Virtual Camera's `Look At` object. Create a script that offsets the GameObject position in the axis that your track is running when you scroll the mouse wheel and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ah alright, I can understand the concept behind how that would work. Now I've got one more issue (for now) - what would I need to type in the code to allow the GO position to offset with my mouse scroll? I'm really not sure how to even begin on that part :((

Comment: Right, within Unity you can use either the [`Input System`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html) or the (old) [`Input`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) class. I've written up a little example that showcases how a GO would move using the old `Input` system using the [`Input. mouseScrollDelta`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mouseScrollDelta.html) over here in the [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/SqynTjiU). If you want to use the new Input System, it'd require a bit more tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself. Create a Dolly Cart in `Cinemachine` and select the Cart in the `Follow` section of the virtual camera.

[image]

Then just connect a position change code to the dolly cart. In the section below, I have added a simple code that works only with clamp and a more advanced code that captures camera noise and makes it smoother. I hope it solves the problem.

### [image]

### SIMPLE

```cs
[SerializeField] private CinemachineDollyCart _dollyCart;
private float y;
private void Update()
{
    y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    _dollyCart.m_Position = Mathf.Clamp01(y); // In position units of Normalized
}
```

---

### COMPLETE

```cs
public class MouseScrollTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private CinemachineDollyCart _dollyCart;

    private float y;

    [Range(0, 10)]
    [SerializeField] private float sensitivity = 1;
    [Range(1, 30)]
    [SerializeField] private float sharpness = 7;
    private void Update()
    {
        // In Position units of Distance
        y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * sensitivity;
        _dollyCart.m_Position = Mathf.Clamp(
            Mathf.Lerp(_dollyCart.m_Position, y, 
                1-Mathf.Exp(-sharpness*Time.unscaledDeltaTime)), 0, _dollyCart.m_Path.PathLength);
    }
}
```